# Minimizing Application in Honeycomb

Tags: android, tablet, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am developing application for honeycomb android tablet. 
I want to know how we can minimize application.
Does any one working on HoneyComb Development.

Thank You.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean...if you press the home button then you will go back to the main screen. Do you want some animation to occur in that space?

Comment: Hi  Robert Massaioli,
          Thanks for reply I want to minimize application to systembar in android 3.0
For more clarification check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835403/tab-application-for-android-honeycomb-3-0

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a service.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

You might be able to use moveTaskToBack(True);
I've not done this though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean)